# How to get Android getExternalStorageDirectory folder by adb?

Tags: android, adb

I want to generate a file while app is running thus my computer can monitor my app status in time(the cell phone is connected via usb all the time).

Is there anyway to let both adb and app point the same directory?

Also, If there has another way to make android can communicate with computer, please tell me.

---

Methods I tried:

At first, I though

```
echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

and

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

would return the same value.

The value adb shell returned:

```
/storage/emulated/legacy
```

However, the result of calling Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() In program is:

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

Then, I make android run shell command

```
        Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
        //also tried "echo \\$EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        su.waitFor();
        in = su.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
            result = result + line + "\n";
        }
        reader.close();
        in.close();
        su.destroy();
        return result;
```

but it return empty string.

Comment: You should know that the contract Android/Windows makes allowing to read/writte is not synchronous. A `File` that was created after the connection was established should not be accessible, even on rooted devices. Likewise, erasing a `File` on the Android, will not make it disappear on the Windows seens directories (Directories are `File`s on the Linux platform, that Android is build upon).

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is not a separate executable but rather a `shell`'s built-in command.

Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c 'echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE'");` instead

Comment: I had tried Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c 'echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE'");. However, it returned me a empty string also.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the value by following command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", "echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE" });
```

Thanks Alex P. inspiring me.